# NameError: name 'b' is not defined python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x

estoy ingresando y aprendiendo apenas todo acerca de este maravilloso mundo de la programacion y eldesarrollo de aplicaciones, para esta ocasion estoy realizando un pequeño juego del ahorcado, un jueguito conocido en varios lugares. Estoy presentando una falla en el codigo, espero me puedan colaborar y me expliquen el por que de mi error, y me den una solucion sin necesidad de cambiar el codigo por completo. les dejo el codigo..

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


# Variables
palabraAdivinar = ''
listaPalabraAdiv = []
listaPalabraMost = []
intentos = 5
letra = ''
run = True

# Logica

## Pedimos la palabra a adivinar
print('AHORCADO')
palabraAdivinar = str(input('Dime una palabra: '))

## Separamos la palabra en letras
listaPalabraAdiv = list(palabraAdivinar)

for item in listaPalabraAdiv:
   listaPalabraMost.append('_')

while run:
   ## Mostramos la palabra a adivinar
   print(' '.join(listaPalabraMost))

   ## Pedimos una letra
   letra = input('Dame una letra: ')

   ## Limpiar pantalla
   for num in range(100):
       print()

   ## Comprueba si se ha equivocado
   fallo = False

   if letra not in listaPalabraAdiv:
       ## Ha fallado
       fallo = True
       intentos = intentos - 1
       print('Has fallado!!!! Te quedan {intentos} intentos'.format(intentos=intentos))
   else:
       ## Adivinado, sustituimos
       for key, value in enumerate(listaPalabraAdiv):
           if value == letra:
               listaPalabraMost[key] = value

   ## Comprueba si ha terminado la partida
   ### Se le acaban los intentos
   if intentos <= 0:
       run = False
       print('Has perdido, la palabra '
             'era "{palabra}"'.format(palabra=''.join(listaPalabraAdiv)))
   elif listaPalabraAdiv == listaPalabraMost:
       run = False
       print('Has ganado, la palabra '
             'era "{palabra}"'.format(palabra=''.join(listaPalabraAdiv)))
```

El programa me comienza a correr bien, pero al momento de ingresarle una letra al juego me sale un error. Un ejemplo, en este caso le ingreso la letra b, el codigo de error es el siguiente:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ahorcado.py", line 16, in <module>
    palabraAdivinar = str(input('Dime una palabra: '))
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'b' is not defined
```

como les mencione anteriormente, apenas estoy ingresando a este maravilloso mundo por lo cual pido colaboracion para que me expliquen mi error. muchas gracias colegas.

Comment: también probé tu código en python 3 y funciona perfecto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu código está bien, se me ocurre que lo estás corriendo con Python 2 en lugar de Python 3.

---

Tomando esta línea para explicar `palabraAdivinar = str(input('Dime una palabra: '))`

En Python 2 `input` llama automáticamente a [eval()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) la cual evalúa el argumento como expresión python.

Es decir, si tenes una variable `x=1` y a `input` le pasas `x+1` te va a retornar 2, porque evalúa la expresión `x+1`. Si le pasas `perro`, sin comillas, piensa que es una variable, no un string, por eso te dice que no está definida.

---

En tu caso querés un string, entonces el usuario debería pasar la palabra con comillas `'perro'`; o usar `raw_input()` en lugar de `input()`, raw_input toma al argumento como `string`, que es lo que vos estás buscando.

Ahora bien, viendo que pusiste la etiqueta **python-3.x**, en python 3.x el *viejo input* no existe más y el *nuevo input* es el que en python 2 se conocía como `raw_input()`, es decir, `input()` entiende que el argumento es un string en vez de una expresión. Por lo que el str() que usas en esa linea de ejemplo está de más, ya que input retorna un string.

#### Conclusión:

Deberías ejecutar tu código en un entorno que tenga Python 3.x y va a funcionar sin que cambies nada.

Por consola podrías ejecutarlo con `python3 ahorcado.py`

Comment: muchas gracias, ese era el problems lo estaba ejecutando desde la terminal pero con python 2 y lo habia hecho cin python 3